# Remove empty space left behind the conditional rendering

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my VF code

```
<div id="addservices-section" class="tab-pane fade">                            
<apex:outputPanel >
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="addservices-display-table" class="table table-bordred table-detailed">
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!fds.Additional_Review__c}">Additional Review&nbsp;<apex:outputField id="as-c1" value="{!fds.Additional_Review__c}"/></apex:outputPanel><br/>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!fds.Advice_one_off_Additional__c}">Advice one-off (Additional)&nbsp;<apex:outputField id="as-c2" value="{!fds.Advice_one_off_Additional__c}"/></apex:outputPanel><br/>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!fds.Aged_care_advice__c}">Aged care advice&nbsp;<apex:outputField id="as-c3" value="{!fds.Aged_care_advice__c}"/></apex:outputPanel><br/>
        </table>
    </div>                        
</apex:outputPanel>
```

As can be seen I have embedded each of the 3 fields to be displayed within an `apex:outputpanel` tag of their own.

The idea is to render only the fields if the boolean for those fields is true.

In my test record the value for the 2nd field (Advice One Off Additional) is false.

So I expected the 1st and 3rd fields to be shown. This is happening.
I expected the 2nd to be hidden. This is also happening.

But in the UI there is a glaring "empty space" present between the 1st field (Additional Review) and the 3rd field (Banking Assistance) as shown below.

[image]

Any ideas how to remove the space.

I believe I can achieve this via a roundabout jQuery but I would like to hear out other options.

Comment: I believed the conditional rendering is not supposed to leave "ghost" spaces...or am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `<br/>` tags after each apex:outputpanel instead of within the outputpanel. So they basically are always being rendered which is why you have the extra line break.

```
<apex:outputpanel...>...</apex:outputPanel><br/>
<apex:outputpanel...>...</apex:outputPanel><br/>
<apex:outputpanel...>...</apex:outputPanel><br/>
```

This is essentially rendered as:

```
outputpanel 1 <br/>
<br/>
outputpanel 3 <br/>
```

Easiest way to fix this is to just move the `<br/>` tags within your outputpanels:

```
<apex:outputpanel...>...<br/></apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputpanel...>...<br/></apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputpanel...>...<br/></apex:outputPanel>
```